# .ogg audio file and aplay white noise

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa

I am trying to play a .ogg audio file to alert me when a `rsync` operation is done. However when `aplay` is playing the file it just creates white static noise. The manual entry only says .aiff are not supported.

The specific command is `aplay -f dat /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Im-Irc-Event.ogg`

Comment: Can any other programs play that ogg file? What does the ogg file have to do with aiff?

Comment: Yes, VLC can play the files. The .aiff part was just to clarify that the manual entry says the only filetype not playable is aiff, not necessarily .ogg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot decode `ogg` files with `aplay`. According to the man page, the only formats `aplay` understands are `voc`, `wav`, `raw` and `au`. My guess is that `aplay` interprets the `ogg` file as raw data, hence the white noise.

Use some other program that can actually decode `ogg` files, like `paplay`, or third-party programs, e.g. `mplayer`, `ogg123` etc.

Comment: Thanks, that was a quick one. Must have overseen it when reading the manual.

Comment: Or try `paplay` (*It understands all audio file formats supported by libsndfile*) or `vlc` can play only in a terminal too. Or `sox` (Debian + others?) has `play`